# Babel usage in web app - node, react, gulp, browserify

Tags: node.js, reactjs, gulp, browserify, babeljs

I would like to start using advanced JS features in an pre-existing app with a NodeJS serverside, React using the Fluxible architecture, Gulp task runner and Broserify/CommonJS front end modules.

Anybody who has been down that path or a similar path before and wants to share some insight I would much appreciate it.

Comment: The front end I pretty much grok, using `babelify` as a transform. My difficulty is in the understanding that `babel-node` is not advisable in production, and in how to organize a separate compile/transpile step, followed by running the app using `node` as I already do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`babel-node` compiles on-the-fly. You can use the API (`babel-core`) to pre-compile and then run the compiled output in node. There's also a [gulp-babel](https://github.com/babel/gulp-babel) plugin. At the expense of extra processing overhead at build time you could hijack `browserify` or use `module-deps` to figure out the dependency graph for you, if relevant. There's a notion of adding a feature to Babel to generate a dependency graph, but it's not available currently.

Comment: Exactly it is this pre-compile step, using `babel-core` that I am interested in. I suppose I am looking for examples of its usage.

Comment: Yes, that would be using the CLI. If I had a scripted build system I'd use an API: e.g. if you're using `gulp`, probably use `gulp-babel` (e.g. something like `gulp.src('src/**/*.js`).pipe(gulpbabel()).pipe(gulp.dest('lib')`) or without `gulp` use a glob library, like `glob`, to do the same thing and call `babel.transform()` (from `babel-core`) on each match and write it to `lib/`.